# In Azure Web app logs are not getting archived even after reaching maxFileSize

Tags: spring-boot, azure, logging, azure-web-app-service, logback

I have deployed a Java application in Azure webapp with following logback-spring.xml:

```
<appender name="JiraIFRealtimeAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_REALTIME_PATH}/Jira/Jira-Publisher-Realtime-Webapp.log
        </file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_REALTIME_PATH}/Jira/Archived-Logs/Jira-Publisher-Realtime-Webapp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each file should be at most 6MB, keep 20 days worth of history, but at most 2GB -->
            <!-- each archived file, size max 6MB -->
            <maxFileSize>6MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 2GB, it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>2GB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- keep 20 days worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>20</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
```

Here the expectation is current log file should move to archived files once it reaches the maxFileSize to 6MB, but logs are not even getting archived after reaching 40MB in Azure web app. But on local the logs are working fine.

Can anyone please help me resolving this issue?

Thanks and Regards,
Preethi H R

Answer (score 0):

- Check `LOG_REALTIME_PATH` environment variable is set correctly in your Azure web app. You can also try to modify the `maxFileSize` and `totalSizeCap` values to smaller sizes to see if the log files are being archived correctly.
- Set the `totalSizeCap` to 6MB, you can set the value to `6291456` (which is 6 * 1024 * 1024). Setting the `totalSizeCap` to a smaller value may cause older log files to be deleted more frequently.

[image]

- I have another way, Use Azure Blob Storage to store the log files instead of the file system.
- It can help to avoid the limitations of the file system and provide more flexibility in managing the log files. You can use the Azure Blob Storage Appender for Logback to write the log files to Azure Blob Storage.

```xml
<appender  name="azureBlobAppender"  class="com.microsoft.azure.logback.AzureBlobAppender">
        <storageConnectionString>DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=mykey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net</storageConnectionString>
        <containerName>mycontainer</containerName>
        <blobNamePattern>{appName}/{sys:component}/{sys:hostname}/{sys:pid}/{date}/{level}.log</blobNamePattern>
        <maxSizeRollBackups>10</maxSizeRollBackups>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <uploadRetryCount>10</uploadRetryCount>
        <uploadRetryDelayMillis>5000</uploadRetryDelayMillis>
        <layout  class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
</appender>
```

Reference :

- Check [Azure Blob Appender](https://github.com/m-moris/log4j2-azure-blob-appender#azure-blob-appender)
- check how to send logs to [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#send-logs-to-azure-monitor)

Comment: Hi Suresh, Thank you very much for your reply. I have cross checked LOG_REALTIME_PATH environment variable is set correctly in our Azure web app and to highlight Logs are getting archived only on restarting the web app. But are not archiving without restarting. Can you please suggest what would be exactly the case here?

Comment: Azure Web App uses a read-only file system for the deployed application, and any changes made to the file system are not immediately reflected. Instead, the changes are effective only after a restart of the application. Please check [Automatically reloading configuration file upon modification](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan)